# Why the Page_Load Event is not able to Get Updated Values from xml file in C# Asp.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, pageload

I am trying to build a WebPage that includes "Rating of Site". Instead of using Database i am storing two variables to compute Avg of Rating in xml file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <RatingCount>6</RatingCount>
  <RatingTotal>17</RatingTotal>
</data>
```

Here is my Logic Code Both On the Page Load and AJAX Rating Control

Page_Load()

```
string rootPath = Server.MapPath("~/");
        if (File.Exists(rootPath + "data.xml"))
        {
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load(rootPath + "data.xml");
            XmlNode ratingCount = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/RatingCount");
            XmlNode ratingTotal = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/RatingTotal");
            string rating = ratingTotal.InnerText;
            string count = ratingCount.InnerText;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(count) >= 1)
            {
                double resultRating = Convert.ToSingle(rating) / Convert.ToSingle(count);
                Rating1.CurrentRating = Convert.ToInt32(resultRating);
                lblerror.Text = resultRating + " Rating in " + count + " Totals Votes";
            }
            else
            {
                lblerror.Text = "No Votes Till Now";
            }
        }
```

Rating_Control()

```
string rootPath = Server.MapPath("~/");
            if (File.Exists(rootPath + "data.xml"))
            {
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.Load(rootPath + "data.xml");
                XmlNode ratingCount = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/RatingCount");
                XmlNode ratingTotal = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/RatingTotal");

                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;
                XmlWriter xwrite = XmlWriter.Create(rootPath + @"data.xml", settings);
                xwrite.WriteStartDocument();
                xwrite.WriteStartElement("data");
                string r = (Convert.ToInt32(ratingCount.InnerText) + 1).ToString();
                string t = (Convert.ToInt32(ratingTotal.InnerText) + Convert.ToInt32(e.Value)).ToString();
                xwrite.WriteElementString("RatingCount", r);
                xwrite.WriteElementString("RatingTotal", t);
                xwrite.WriteEndElement();
                xwrite.WriteEndDocument();
                xwrite.Flush();
                xwrite.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                lblerror.Text = "File Doesnt Exists";
            }
```

Any Help will be Appreciated!

Comment: Please add the error message / unexpected behavior that you're seeing.

Comment: the current value of rating is 17 and count is 6. Avg is 2.83
Lets add 4 rating more then rating becomes 21 and count is 7. Avg should display 3. But its remains 2.83. I have to refresh page once more and then output turns as Avg Rating 3. 

so mean to say why its not displaying the Avg at the first time correctly

Comment: Looks like a caching issue. Check your cache settings

Comment: Solved it by Copying the Code of Page_Load() Event in the RangeClick Event(). This problem is solved now.